# Rails - Mongoid : Slow problem between production and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a problem on my Rails application.

I am in version **3.2.22** of rails and **2.2.5** of ruby connect to a mongodb **2.6**.

The problem is that I have huge difference in performance on simple or even more complex queries.

For example :

I run rails c development and then I execute my function (quite complex) it responds after 30 seconds
I run rails c production, I perform the same function as the previous one, it responds after 6 minutes 30 seconds, 7 times slower.
So I try to copy pasted the configuration 'development' in 'production', but the result remains the same, same for the Gemfile.

I look in all the code of the project no difference between the environment production and development.

Do you know the differences in the heart of rails between these two environments? did anyone ever encounter the problem?

Importantly, I am of course connecting to **the same database**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gemfile : https://pastebin.com/ts1h80eg 
Mongoid config (i use docker) : https://pastebin.com/TbHnhzj1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this!

When I saw the number of requests in production, I immediately thought of the query cache.

I found the 'identity_map_enabled' parameter for mongo, so I changed it to true, and hop magic!

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified your mongo (Ruby driver) and mongoid versions, if they are old you may need to upgrade and/or adjust the code to your environment.

To determine whether the slowdown happens in the database or in your application, use command monitoring as described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring

Look at the log entries corresponding to your queries and make note of how log they take in each environment. By implementing a custom event subscriber you can also save the commands being sent and verify that they are identical between the two environments.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, i do the log file, in dev i got 3900 query on my database, and for the same query, i got 18000 query... i dont understand why..